# How do i know which .SO files belong to each framework

Tags: android, abi, libs

i have a big Android project with multiple frameworks. When i generate the APK and unzip it i have multiple `libs/armeabi-v7a/*.so` files - the files names are very different from the frameworks names in the project.

Is there a way to know which .so file is part of which framework?

Comment: i usually  copy them all

Comment: what do you mean? how to you know which framework they belong?

Comment: How many framework you have included? many of the .so files are named after the module they are designed for.

Comment: That is correct, but i still have some .so files without meaningful names. I'm not looking for a workaround or guessing the framework. I'm looking for the way to be sure about it.